# What is the workaround for unstable library feature "core" issue?

Tags: rust, biginteger

I am trying to add big integers together in Rust:

```
extern crate core;
use core::ops::Add;
use num::bigint::{BigInt};
use num::integer::Integer;
...
let mut big = "8705702225074732811211966512111".parse::<BigInt>().unwrap();
let one = "1".parse::<BigInt>().unwrap();
big = big.add(&one);
```

I got the following error:

```
src\main.rs:3:1: 3:19 error: use of unstable library feature 'core': the libcore library has not yet been scrutinized for stabilization in terms of structure and naming (see issue #27701)
src\main.rs:3 extern crate core;
```

Is there any workaround at this time? or is this entirely not doable for the time being?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use the [`std::ops::Add`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Add.html) trait instead of `core::ops::Add`.

```
use std::ops::Add;
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked. Curious though... is there a way to figure out this answer solely based on document, instead of asking in a forum?

Comment: The [documentation for core](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/core/) says that `It is not recommended to use the core library. The stable functionality of libcore is reexported from the standard library.`, and provides a link to the [std](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/) docs.